# Oracle spatial functions without Oracle spatial extensions

Tags: oracle, plsql, spatial, oracle-spatial

I need to save the GPS coordinates in an Oracle database on which are not installed spatial extension.
There is software pl/sql that emulates the main functions of Oracle Spatial (obviously no use its datatype) in the same way to make a "wrap" of JSON functionality of Oracle 11 exists this project on github: https://github.com/pljson/pljson

Comment: does it really _need_ to be done in Oracle? Could you use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) instead?

Comment: oh, and what kind of licence do you have for your Oracle installation? Standard? Enterprise?

Comment: The difficulty lies in having to implement these features in Oracle without spatial extensions and not on another database.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Your database installation already includes Oracle Locator. To confirm, just do: "SQL> describe sdo_geometry". If that fails, then somehow your DBA choose to explicitly remove it (or not install it when he/she created the database) but that is very unlikely. Adding it back in is trivial for the DBA (using the Database Configuration Assistant). Locator provides full support for all 2D vector processing. Spatial extends it with 3D vectors, rasters, point clouds, networks, geocoding and more.

Comment: Just a small point about JSON: Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2) comes with native support for JSON types: not only storing them but also querying and processing.

Comment: Yes but not Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Oracle Locator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL340), it should be installed by default with all editions of Oracle and gives you access to a subset of the features available in Spatial, including the geometry data types you'd need and hopefully some of the functions too, depending on what you need to do with the data.

To check if you have it installed try the following from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> describe sdo_geometry
```

If this succeeds, it's installed, if not, you'll need to ask your friendly neighbourhood DBA to install it for you.

Comment: Just a clarification. Oracle Locator is included with all database editions, and is automatically installed (no separate installation required). It provides full processing for all 2D vector data. Oracle Spatial extends it with support for 3D vectors, rasters, point clouds, networks, geocoding, etc.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind - good info, thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect this.